# Импорт либ из venv

Tags: python-3.x, linux, virtualenv, idle

Я не хочу засорять свою систему миллионом `pip install`ов разных библиотек разных версий, поэтому создал окружение в `/path/env/...` и устанавливаю туда все либы. Также у меня есть кедовский хоткей на вызов `idle` (обычный `idle-python3.9` -> `/usr/bin/idle-python3.9`).

Проблема в том, что либы из env'а я не могу получить в не-env'овской идлешке. Как выход для меня - поменять хоткей `idle-python3.9` на `source /path/env/bin/activate && python -m idlelib`, но тут другая проблема - такой подход не работает :) Точнее, из терминала эта команда работает, а при запуске на хоткее - нет.

`setsid source /home/t/wf/env/bin/activate && python -m idlelib` выдаёт `Команда «python» не найдена.` . Видимо, `setsid` выполняет скрипт входа в env, но не сохраняет окружение.

Как мне сделать, чтобы idle'шка вызывалась из env'а? Либо, чтобы не ставить ударопрочное стекло в микроскоп, как изменить запуск idle хоткеем на `idle-python3.9`, чтобы я мог импортировать либы окружения?

P.S. Я также создавал скрипт, в который по-разному клал вызов `source /home/t/wf/env/bin/activate && python -m idlelib`, но результата это не дало, вызывалась системная ошибка, и, судя по всему, причина та же, что и с `setsid ...`.

Comment: Разрешите поинтересоваться в целях повышения образованности (с) что такое "кедовский хоткей"? Нельзя ли таким хоткеем запусить shell скрипт? Если можно, то в этот скрипт добавьте нужные вам команды, т.е. `source /path/env/bin/activate && python -m idlelib`

Comment: @RomanKonoval да, это тоже была первая мысль, всё равно не работает, как бы я не извращался с вызовом idle. А кедовский хоткей - обычный хоткей, который выполняет команду при нажатии кнопок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Питон 3 сам отлично определяет энв, поэтому можно просто

```
/home/t/wf/env/bin/python -m idlelib
```

Не запустится только если её там вообще нет. Но раз с консоли работает - должно сработать

Также окружение можно задать переменной PYTHON_PATH.

Comment: Не ожидал этого, но сегодня ваш ответ неожиданно пригодился ещё и на работе. Спасибо!